# how to find the solution to this system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the system of equations:

$
xy+xz=54+x^2  \\ 
yx+yz=64+y^2 \\ 
zx+zy=70+z^2 $

Need to find all of the solutions of $ x,y$ and $z$.

Tried to sum up all three equations but got stuck with nothing to factorize.

Comment: According to Maxima, there are thow solutions: algsys([x*y+x*z=54+x^2,y*x+y*z=64+y^2,z*x+z*y=70+z^2],[x,y,z]) = [[x = 9, y = 8, z = 7], [x = - 9, y = - 8, z = - 7]].

Comment: If (x, y, z) is a solution so is (-x, -y, -z).

Comment: @Paul - but how can i use it in here?

Answer (score 1):

First assume $x,y,z\ne 0$.

From equation (1), $y+z=\dfrac {54}{x}+x\Rightarrow y+z-x=\dfrac {54}{x}$     ..........(A1)

From equation (2), $z+x=\dfrac {64}{y}+y\Rightarrow z+x-y=\dfrac {64}{y}$     ..........(A2)

From equation (3), $x+y=\dfrac {70}{z}+z\Rightarrow x+y-z=\dfrac {70}{z}$............(A3)

Now, adding (A1) & (A2), $2xyz=54y+64x$......(B1)

Adding (A2) & (A3), $2xyz=64z+70y$........(B2)

Adding (A3) & (A1), $2xyz=70x+54z$...........(B3)

Equating (B1) & (B2), $64x-16y-64z=0$

Equating (B2) & (B3), $70x-70y-16z=0$

Equating (B3) & (B1), $16x-54y-54z=0$.

Now solve these equations.

Comment: but then you have $x=y=z=0$ which is not true.

Comment: Even worse, $\det\ne 0$ and $x=y=z=0$ is the *only* solution.

Comment: (B2)&(B3) should be: $70x-70y-10z$

Answer (score 1):

with the method above we get $(x,y,z)=\pm (9, 8, 7)$

Answer (score 1):

Adding, $x^{2}$ ,$y^{2}$, & $z^{2}$ to 1st,2nd & 3rd equations respectively we get, 
$x(x+y+z)=2x^{2}+54$
$y(x+y+z)=2y^{2}+64$
$z(x+y+z)=2z^{2}+70$
So, $\dfrac{2x^{2}+54}{x}=\dfrac{2y^{2}+64}{y}=\dfrac{2z^{2}+70}{z}=x+y+z=k(say)$
From these, $2x^{2}-kx+54=0,2y^{2}-ky+64=0,2z^{2}-kz+70=0$.
So, $x=\dfrac{k\pm \sqrt{k^{2}-4.2.54}}{4}, y=\dfrac{k\pm \sqrt{k^{2}-4.2.64}}{4}, z=\dfrac{k\pm \sqrt{k^{2}-4.2.70}}{4}$.
Putting, $k=24$,& taking only positive sign we get, $x=9,y=8,z=7$.
Note that, $x+y+z=24$. So, if we take negative sign then $x=3,y=4,z=5$, in that case $x+y+z\ne 24$. So, it is not admissible.
Again, if we take, $k=-24$ then the solutions are $x=-9,y=-8,z=-7$ 7 in this case sum is also $-24$.

Comment: Excellent approach.........Is it true for all values of $k$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

> $ x ( x+y+z - 2 x ) =54 \, ;  y  (x-y+z- 2 y )=64 \,;  z (x+y+z- 2 z)=70 $

Comment: can't see how does it help